# Event-level independence does not imply random-variable independence for non-binary random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A single event-level independence $(x^0⊥y^0)$ does not imply the random variable level independence $X⊥Y$ for non-binary random variables. By non-binary I mean, random variables has more than two events i.e. $x^0, x^1, x^2$ are all possible and likewise $y^0, y^1, y^2$ are also possible.

Intuitively, I am clear that this could be proven by using CPTs but I was wondering if there is some better way to prove such statements.

Comment: Any particular reason for downvote? I am not looking for solution, I am looking for ways to tackle this type of problems.

Comment: What is $x^0$ in your notation?

Comment: An event in which random variable X has a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

> The event-level independence does not imply the random variable level independence for non-binary random variables.

Doesn't it?

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete and that every pair of events $[X=x]$ and $[Y=y]$ is independent (this is probably what you call event-level independence), then, for every $A$ and $B$,
$$
P(X\in A,Y\in B)=\sum_{(x,y)\in A\times B}P(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_{(x,y)\in A\times B}P(X=x)P(Y=y),
$$
hence
$$
P(X\in A,Y\in B)=\sum_{x\in A}P(X=x)\sum_{y\in B}P(Y=y)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B),
$$
that is, $X$ and $Y$ are independent (which is probably what you call random variable-level independence).

Comment: I probably should modify my question. I meant a single event-level independence. If there is a single event that is independent, i.e. for value of X as 0 and Y as 0, only this case is independent, for other event there is no such assumption